# Suppose that triangle $ABC$ is an isosceles triangle with $AB = AC$, and that $D$ is a point on the same side of BC as A such that ∠BAC = 2∠BDC

Tags: geometry

Suppose that triangle $ABC$ is an isosceles triangle with $AB = AC$, and that $D$ is a point on the same side of $BC$ as $A$ such that $∠BAC = 2∠BDC$. Show that $AD = AB$

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P7kg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's draw a circumcircle of triangle $BCD$.

Because $∠BAC$ is 2 times larger than $∠BDC$, the angle $∠BAC$ is equal to the central angle of a circumcircle.

Assume that the circumcircle have the center in point $O$. Then we have the triangle $OBC$, that is isosceles with $|OB|=|OC|$ and $∠BOC= ∠BAC$. Thats enough to say, that the triangles $ABC$ and $OBC$ are congruent.

$∠BAC < 180^{\circ}$, so $∠BDC < 90^{\circ}$. The point $O$ is then on the same side of $AB$ as point $D$.

Assuming, that $A$ and $D$ are on the same side of $BC$, point $A$ is equal to the centre of our circumcircle, so it's distance to any of points $B$, $C$ and $D$ is equal, and $|AD|=|AB|$.

Comment: Inside $\triangle BDC$, there are numerous points can be “A” (such that $\angle BAC$ is 2 times larger than $\angle BDC$). Need to say more before we can conclude that particular “A” makes $\angle BAC$ the central angle of the suggested circum-circle.

Comment: @Mick thank you for comment. I've edited my answer.